# Python not returning any MySQL results

Tags: python, mysql

Can anybody tell me why this is not returning any results? I'm trying to copy data from a `JSON` column into a new column, multiply those results by **10%** and then display the original population next to the 10% increased population.

Python seems to run this, but returns no result.

```
try:
      query = ("UPDATE city SET Population = info->'$.Population' WHERE info->'$.Population' > 0")
      cursor.execute(query)
      conn.commit()

except Exception as ex:
    print("cursor execution failure: " + str(ex))
query = ("SET Population = Population * 1.1")
cursor.execute(query)
conn.commit()
except Exception as ex:
    print("cursor execution failure: " + str(ex))
query = ("SELECT Name, info->’$.Population’, Population FROM city;")
cursor.execute(query)

except Exception as ex:
        print("cursor execution failure: " + str(ex))
    for row in cursor:
        print(u"{:<45} {:<45}".format(*row))
```

Comment: I don't understand the line: SET population... Either population is a column or it's a variable, but you have to decide which

Comment: Population is a column. I added in UPDATE city (city is the table name).

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax for SET is false you have to replace:

```
query = ("SET Population = Population * 1.1")
```

by

```
query = ("UPDATE city SET Population = Population * 1.1")
```